# Find if the same value appear in two lists

Tags: vb.net, list, duplicates

I have two lists with almost the same value. I want to remove from the second list every row with the same username in it.

```
ListA                    ListB
Col1   Col2   Col3       Col1   Col2   Col3
1222   User1  2018       1111   User1  2019
1234   User2  2018       1456   User10 2018
2333   User3  2018       2345   User5  2018
```

I try this :

```
listA = listB.Except(listA).toList
```

What I want to do is remove the row with User1 in listA. But since the row is not exactly the same what I try didn't work.

I only found who to remove the exact same row from two list, so far.
I'm still learn to code. I have a vague idea that I need to loop into both list but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: Are these lists List(Of T)?

Comment: Instead of trying to find ready-made code, start by considering what the logic is that you need to implement.  That's not even programming so anyone can do it.  If these were physical objects and you had to perform this process manually what steps would you perform?  Those steps are your algorithm.  Pick up a pen and paper and write down that algorithm. Once you have a working algorithm, THEN you can start to write to implement that specifically. If you don't have an algorithm, i.e. you don't know what the code is supposed to do, it's no surprise you can't write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListViews as following:

```
Private Sub btnCompare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompare.Click

    Dim rowToDel As Integer
    Dim x, y, maxx, maxy As Integer
    maxy = ListView2.Items.Count
    maxx = ListView1.Items.Count

    For x = 0 To maxx - 1 ' ListView1 Rows

        For y = 0 To maxy - 1 ' ListView2 Rows

            If y < maxy Then

                If ListView1.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text = ListView2.Items(y).SubItems(1).Text Then

                    rowToDel = y
                    ListView2.Items(y).Remove()
                    ListView2.Refresh()
                    maxy = maxy - 1 ' Reduce ListView2 Max row

                End If

            End If

        Next

    Next


End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Adding ListView Columns
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Col1", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Col2", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Col3", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

    ListView2.Columns.Add("Col1", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView2.Columns.Add("Col2", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView2.Columns.Add("Col3", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)

    Dim str(3) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem

    str(0) = "1111"
    str(1) = "User1"
    str(2) = "2017"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

    str(0) = "1113"
    str(1) = "User2"
    str(2) = "2017"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

    str(0) = "1114"
    str(1) = "User3"
    str(2) = "2018"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)

    str(0) = "2211"
    str(1) = "User3"
    str(2) = "2019"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView2.Items.Add(itm)

    str(0) = "2222"
    str(1) = "User4"
    str(2) = "2019"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView2.Items.Add(itm)

    str(0) = "2223"
    str(1) = "User1"
    str(2) = "2019"
    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
    ListView2.Items.Add(itm)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ListA As New List(Of Row)
    Private ListB As New List(Of Row)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ListA.Add(New Row(1222, "User1", 2018))
        ListA.Add(New Row(1234, "User2", 2018))
        ListA.Add(New Row(2333, "User3", 2018))

        ListB.Add(New Row(1111, "User1", 2019))
        ListB.Add(New Row(1456, "User10", 2018))
        ListB.Add(New Row(2345, "User5", 2018))

        ListB.ForEach(Function(b) ListA.RemoveAll(Function(a) a.Col2 = b.Col2))

        ' If you want to use a for each loop.
        'For Each b As Row In ListB
        '    For Each a As Row In ListA.ToArray
        '        If a.Col2 = b.Col2 Then
        '            ListA.Remove(a)
        '        End If
        '    Next
        'Next

    End Sub

End Class

Class Row

    Property Col1 As Integer
    Property Col2 As String
    Property Col3 As Integer

    Public Sub New(value1 As Integer, value2 As String, value3 As Integer)
        Col1 = value1
        Col2 = value2
        Col3 = value3
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for using `IEqualityComparer` [Except(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__)
and a short answer is

```
listA = listB.Except(listA, New MyComparer).toList
```

**Explanation**

Let's have a class which is contained in the lists

```
Private Class TestClass
    Property Prop1 As String
    Property Prop2 As String
End Class
```

Let's have two lists

```
    Dim listA As New Generic.List(Of TestClass)
    Dim listB As New Generic.List(Of TestClass)
```

We want values to be almost the same for example `Prop1` is equal and `Prop2` does not matter. So we define a comparer

```
Private Class MyComparer
        Implements Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of TestClass)

        Public Function Equals1(x As TestClass, y As TestClass) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TestClass).Equals
            Return x.Prop1 = y.Prop1
        End Function

        Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As TestClass) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TestClass).GetHashCode
            Return obj.Prop1.GetHashCode
        End Function
End Class
```

And using the comparer

```
Dim res = listB.Except(listA, New MyComparer)
```

**Note**

You have to be careful with a hash code. Equal objects must always have the same hashs.
When hash different object is same the code works but is slower.